# Running Runnable in CompletableFuture multiple time

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8, java.util.concurrent

I want to execute multiple threads which will try to add concurrently to my custom list `MyList` , but I do not see any output when i try to get count

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyList<String> list = new list<String>();

        MyRunner<String> myRunner = new MyRunner<String>(list);

        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            CompletableFuture.runAsync(new MyRunner<String>(list));
        }

        try {
            threadPool.awaitTermination(100l, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(list.getCount());
}
```

Runner class :

```
class MyRunner<String> implements Runnable {

    MyList<String> list;

    public MyRunner(MyList <String> t) {
        this.list = t;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            list((String) (i + Thread.currentThread().getName()));
        }

    }
}
```

class MyList :

```
public class MyList<T> {

    Queue<T> blockingQueue;
    Lock lock;

    long count;

    public MyList() {
        blockingQueue = new LinkedList<>();
        count = 0;
        lock = new ReentrantLock();
    }

    public void add(T singleTon) {
        lock.lock();
        blockingQueue.offer(singleTon);
        count +=1;
        lock.unlock();
    }

    public long getCount() {
        return count;
    }


}
```

Follow up question :

using `CountDownLatch` the program is not ending. the number of sysout is 10001 and last output being `In runnable: 9 : pool-1-thread-1`

`CountDownLatch` implementation :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        MyList<String> mylist = new MyList<>();

        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(10);

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);


        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            CompletableFuture.runAsync(new MyRunner<String>(mylist, latch), executorService);
        }

        latch.await();

        System.out.println(mylist.count);
    }


class MyRunner<String> implements Runnable {

    MyList<String> mylist;
    CountDownLatch latch;

    public MyRunner(MyList<String> mylist, CountDownLatch latch) {
       this.latch = latch;
       this.mylist = mylist;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("In runnable: "+ i + " : "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
            mylist.add((String)("" + i));
        }

        latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

Comment: hint: are you using that thread pool at all? and IDE will show you that...

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Not only does the code you have posted not compile, but it doesn't contain important information, such as your list implementation.

Comment: @assylias : Question edited. It also includes the `CountDownLatch` implementation now.

Comment: Latch has count `10`, you loop `1000` times. See a problem? Also, you never `shutdown` the `ExecutorService` and your threads aren’t daemon so the program will never finish.

Comment: That was it! May be a follow up question ( or will post in new thread) as to the behavior of CountDownLatch in case where the countdown is less than number of Runnables

Comment: That should be obvious - it will release your main thread early, after the first 10 tasks complete. The documentation is very clear - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html#countDown()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You invoke `CompletableFuture.runAsync(Runnable runnable)` that doesn't use the `Executor` that you created.
Use instead `CompletableFuture.runAsync(Runnable runnable, Executor executor)` by passing your `Executor` instance such as :

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(new MyRunner<String>(list), threadPool);
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. Looks like I was not waiting enough for the result to come out.

Comment: Followup: Is there some best practice around right waiting time for all threads to finish?

Comment: @NoviceUser `CountDownLatch` most probably is what you would need to look at

Comment: @Eugene : I gave it a shot ( question edited to have `CountDownLatch `implementation ), but the program does not terminate. Any ideas?

Comment: @NoviceUser your question has been answered and you accepted the answer, you cannot now edit the question and ask more questions. You need to create a new question.

Comment: @davidxxx when does it make more sense to use runAsync with an explicit Executor?